# ORDER BY Error for Associated Rails Models with Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a Single Table Inheritance Model like the following:

```
class Application < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :snapshots, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :foos, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Snapshot < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Foo < Snapshot
end
```

The Snapshot/Foo class has a date with the variable name 'when'
When I add :order => 'when' (or :when) to the has_many (foos) relationship the database throws an error when I access the object.
e.g. application.foos.each...

Generated Query:

```
SELECT "snapshots".* FROM "snapshots"  WHERE "snapshots"."type" IN ('Foo') AND "snapshots"."application_id" = 25 ORDER BY when
```

*Error Near "when":syntax error

If I manually edit the query and enter it in the rails dbconsole:

```
SELECT "snapshots".* FROM "snapshots"  WHERE "snapshots"."type" IN ('Foo') AND "snapshots"."application_id" = 25 ORDER BY "snapshots"."when"
```

The query works.

Is this a known rails 3 bug or is there some special syntax?  Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Try by timing

```
  query.order(:when)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT *FROM snapshots where type IN ('Foo') AND application_id = 25 ORDER BY when
```

Answer (score 0):

After Trying a number of things this worked:

```
@application.foos.order("\"snapshots\".\"when\"")
```

which generated the query with the appropriate "snapshots"."when"